# How can i write a code part which always run on my webserver.ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

i need to write a code to update my database at 7 a.m. and 7 p.m. everyday.So i think this code have to always run on my web server and update my database.**How can i make this code always running?**
Can anyone help me about this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely have to achieve that by writing a script in the database, if it's the database itself which you want to update. Also, if so you'll have to give more details including which DBMS you're using and what the context behind this update is.

Comment: I am using MySql with ASP.NET.I crawl a web site context and show it on my web site,But this context change two times a day and i need every update data which occurs on this web site.
If my page runs before update of this web site there is no problem but if my page does not have user between this time period i will miss this update.So i have to seperate this operation from my website.
i hope i could explain the problem :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a cron script (on linux webserver) or in windows schedule a task. Either way, you will need a command line script (or batch file) that starts the task for you twice a day. In windows, that would probably be a VB script which then makes the procedure run to update the database or calls the program to update the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the good suggesting for that I read in Jeff Atwood article:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Checkout, so it might suite for you as well.